# Generic call signatures and type inference

Tags: typescript

I have the following two snippets:
1.

```
interface Identity {
    <T extends any>(arg: T): T
}

function identity<T>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

let id: Identity = identity

id() // the argument here is of type unknown
```

2. 

```
interface Identity<E> {
    <T extends E>(arg: T): T
}

function identity<T>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

let id: Identity<any> = identity

id() // the argument here is of type any
```

In the first case I have a named [ObjectType](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#383-object-type-literals) with a generic call signature, introduced through an [interface declaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#71-interface-declarations), and in the second case I have a [generic interface declaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#71-interface-declarations), that when instantiated gives the same [ObjectType](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#383-object-type-literals) with the same generic call signature. So, AFAIK, in both cases I should get this [ObjectType](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#383-object-type-literals) in both of the [TypeReference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#382-type-references)s:

```
{
    <T extends any>(arg: T): T
}
```

But when calling the `id` function, in the first case, the argument is of type `unknown` and in the second case it's of type `any`. Can someone clarify the differences between the two snippets? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I observed the same behavior with these two interfaces:

```
interface Identity1 {
    <T extends any>(arg: T): T // -> unknown
}

interface Identity2 {
    <T extends E, E = any>(arg: T): T // -> any
}
```

The answer to your question: there is no type theoretical difference between the two snippets. The difference you observe has something to do with the way the compiler operates under these different conditions and nothing to do with type theory.

So why does the TypeScript compiler do this?

To know for sure we'd have to look at the way TypeScript is implemented. I can make an educated guess though:

The `any` type has been around since the start of TypeScript, whereas `unknown` was introduced much later. The compiler therefore probably still plays a simplification trick that reduce `T extends any` to simply `T`, whereas it can not apply that same simplification when `T` is dependant on `E`.

Back in the day, before `unknown` was introduced, `any` was the default type for types that can not be inferred, which is the case when you do not pass parameters. That time this simplification was perfectly fine, but now that `unknown` is the new default uninferred type you get this inconsistency.

Note:

```
interface Identity1b {
    <T extends any>(arg: T): T // -> unknown
}

interface Identity1a {
    <T>(arg: T): T // -> unknown
}
```